# Accessing AWS Lambda environment variables in Java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The AWS has introduced Environment variables for accessing in the Lambda function. I could not find any documentation which shows how to access the environment variables from the Lambda function using Java. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

you can get them with:

```
System.getenv("NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE")
```

Comment: Just a note, in windows (**in general**), we should restart our IDE if the environment variable was created **after** the IDE is opened.

Comment: @RichardLee what?

Comment: Hi @MarcioB, so, i'm using IntelliJ and i had to restart it, but it does not appeared so obvious to me at first moment. Just for help someone with it.

Comment: @RichardLee but those are environment variables inside a lambda in AWS, so why do you need to create them in your OS?

Comment: To do test locally

Comment: Will it give the same result with System.getProperty() ?

Comment: You will need to setup SAM Local for this purpose and you can then easily set the environment variable in a separate file and provide at run time.

Comment: I also used same thing recently.

Answer (score 4):

If You are using Spring Core then PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer class can be initialized  as a part of Configuration and then 
@Value("${RESOURCE_URL}") annotation can be used to access environment variables.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Value("${RESOURCE_URL}")
private String url;
```

Comment: In a lambda aws we can use spring ?

Comment: yes, you can, but only use bare minimum dependency to keep the jar size small.

Comment: In this case, if I want to use @Bean, what it's de minimun dependency that's have to use ?

Comment: sadly this does not work for me. i'm using spring-boot 3.
Configuration
Getter
public class Config {

    Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    Value("${SFTP_USERNAME:test_user}")
    private String username;
};

Answer (score 0):

I am using this -

```
System.getenv("VAR_NAME");
```

This works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you define environment variable in aws lambda with key as "MyKey" and value as "XYX" then I will use:

```
System.getenv("MyKey");
```