# How do I fetch my data from properties file in java project and make it work in my alexa skill?

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

I have an alexa skill developed where I am connecting to a DB. I don't want the User name and password to be visible in my code. I tried to fetch them via properties file in java project, however it works locally but does not work when I deploy my alexa skill as a JAR file in AWS console. Please help me here.

Comment: I think you should be using Environment Variables instead for this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-env_console.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094954/accessing-aws-lambda-environment-variables-in-java-code may help.

Comment: Thanks Amit, this worked. I should have known this simple and useful feature earlier. Thanks again :)